# How to add a column to a datagrid for a selected item in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, class, xaml, methods

I have a datagrid which looks like this.

[image]

I want for the user to be able to manually enter the date after clicking 'Add Interview DT' for a selected item in the 'Interview Date and time' column.

My code so far for Shortlist.xaml.cs is like this:

```
List<ShortlistedClient> shlclients = new List<ShortlistedClient>();

public Shortlist()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = shlclients;
    shlclients.Add(new ShortlistedClient("Rich", "07515118265", "rich@gmail.com", "Glasgow", "Office", "MSc", "more than 3 years", "Yes", "No"));
    shlclients.Add(new ShortlistedClient("Steve", "07515118265", "steve@gmail.com", "Glasgow", "Construction", "High School", "more than 3 years", "Yes", "No"));
    shlclients.Add(new ShortlistedClient("Maria", "07485999005", "mb@gmail.com", "Edinburgh", "Office", "MSc", "more than 3 years", "No", "No"));
}

// remove shortlisted client
private void RemoveShClient(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgr.Items.Count >= 1)
    {
        if (dgr.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            var items = (List<ShortlistedClient>)dgr.ItemsSource;

            var item = (ShortlistedClient)dgr.SelectedValue;
            dgr.ItemsSource = null;
            dgr.Items.Clear();
            items.Remove(item);
            dgr.ItemsSource = items;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No Clients Found");
    }
}
```

So I need help with writing this method:

```
// method to fill in data for the date and time column 
private void addInterviewDT(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShClient sc = dgr.SelectedItem as ShClient;
   
    if (sc != null)
    {
        ?
    }
}
```

My Client and ShortlistedClient classes are defined as follows:

```
public partial class Client
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; }
    public string Worktype { get; }
    public string Qualification { get; }
    public string Workexp { get; }
    public string Drlicence { get; }
    public string Crconviction { get; }
    public bool IDed { get; private set; }

    public Client(string n, string p, string e, string l, string wt, string q, string we, string dl, string cc)
    {
        Name = n;
        Phone = p;
        Email = e;
        Location = l;
        Worktype = wt;
        Qualification = q;
        Workexp = we;
        Drlicence = dl;
        Crconviction = cc;

    }
}
```

```
public class ShortlistedClient : Client
{

    public DateTime DT { get; set; }
    public bool InterestedinVac { get; private set; }


    public List<ShortlistedClient> clients { get; set; } = new List<ShortlistedClient>();
    public ShortlistedClient(string n, string p, string e, string l, string wt, string q, string we, string dl, string cc) : base(n, p, e, l, wt, q, we, dl, cc)
    {
        DT = new DateTime();
        InterestedinVac = false;
     
    }
}
```

And my code for the Shortlist.xaml is this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp_Employment_Help.Shortlist"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp_Employment_Help"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Shortlist" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel Margin="27,0,0,77">
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgr" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" CanUserAddRows="False" Height="154" Width="760">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Email}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone" Binding="{Binding Phone}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" Binding="{Binding Location}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Worktype" Binding="{Binding Worktype}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qualification" Binding="{Binding Qualification}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Workexp" Binding="{Binding Worktype}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Driving licence" Binding="{Binding Drlicence}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Criminal conviction" Binding="{Binding Crconviction}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Interview Date and time" Binding="{Binding DT}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Add Interview DT" Width="128" FontWeight="Bold" Height="28"/>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="120" Height="46"/>
        <Button x:Name="BtnRemoveShlClient" Content="Remove Shortlisted Client" FontWeight="Bold" Height="33" Width="221" Click="RemoveShClient"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Additionally, how can I show my Interview date and time column values as empty instead of '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM'?

thank you, I'm new to C# and wpf.

Comment: Where are you supposed to enter the time? In the `TextBox`?

Comment: Yes.  or it could be a Label? not sure which one would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `ShortlistedClient` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for you to be able to dynamically set one of its properties and have the UI updated automatically:

```
public class ShortlistedClient : Client, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime _dt;
    public DateTime DT
    {
        get { return _dt; }
        set { _dt = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public bool InterestedinVac { get; private set; }

    public List<ShortlistedClient> clients { get; set; } = new List<ShortlistedClient>();
    public ShortlistedClient(string n, string p, string e, string l, string wt, string q, string we, string dl, string cc) : base(n, p, e, l, wt, q, we, dl, cc)
    {
        DT = new DateTime();
        InterestedinVac = false;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You can then parse the value of the `TextBox` and try to set the property:

```
private void addInterviewDT(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShortlistedClient sc = dgr.SelectedItem as ShortlistedClient;

    if (sc != null && DateTime.TryParse(textBox.Text, out DateTime value))
    {
        sc.DT = value;
    }
}
```

`textBox` is the name of the `TextBox` control:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="textBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="120" Height="46"/>
```

> additionally, how can I show my Interview date and time column values as empty instead of '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM'?

Change the type of the `DT` property to `Nullable<DateTime>`.

Comment: where do I change to Nullable<DateTime>?

Comment: In `ShortlistedClient` or whatever your class is called: `public DateTime? DT { get; set; }`

Comment: nope, I have tried public Nullable<DateTime>. DT { get; set; }, it does not make any difference.

Comment: thank you for the explanation though. If I have just used string instead of DateTime, would it be easier to get it as value out of TextBox?

Comment: Obviously you should set that property to `null` (or `default(DateTime?)` instead of `DateTime.MinValue` or `default(DateTime)`.

Comment: The value of a `TextBox` is always a `string`. You need to convert this value into a `DateTime` using the `DateTime.Parse` method.

Comment: I just dont know what else to choose for date entry.. is there anything better than TextBox?

Comment: You could use a `DatePicker`. And then get the value directly from its `SelectedDate` property.

Comment: I like that. thank you v much. I might ask another question of how to do the same with a DatePicker!

Comment: Another error is CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) .....Shortlist.xaml.cs 68 Active

Comment: by the way, I have tried to extract time only with (sc != null && DateTime.TryParse(textBox.Text, out TimeOnly value) but it gives an error, do you know how to extract only time or date?